# STM32 HAL vs Freertos HAL

Tags: freertos

I am using stm32 bluepill board along with Freertos.

I understand that ST provides HAL drivers for peripherals for their MCUs (https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1725-description-of-stm32f4-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
Also Freertos provides HAL drivers (http://freertoshal.github.io/doxygen/group__HAL.html)

The HAL drivers provided ST is micro-controller specific hence can understand its working.

But freertos is not micro-controller specific. I wanted to know how Freertos HAL drivers interact with hardware?

Answer (score 1):

FreeRTOS is just an "OS" which provides you a framework to run any code you want within that framework.

It does not need to provide any drivers or HAL for any peripherals, as it does not need them or know about them.

You can use any drivers you want, including the HAL provided by ST.

Comment: I understand Freertos is a kernel. Usually drivers are saved in kernel. That made me to ask question. Are you sure freertos kernel doesn't house any driver?

Comment: @DeepakKumar FreeRTOS is just the kernel. It does not come with any drivers as you can use whatever drivers you used before adding FreeRTOS and moving to run your code under FreeRTOS. You don't ask the FreeRTOS kernel to do IO for you.